# Error in Displaying Queue

Tags: c#, queue

I'm trying to implement a Queue class that supports a Min method, which returns the minimum value stored in the queue, and throws an exception if the queue is empty.

Howerver when I tried to run the program the queue displayed is not as I expeted. I enqueue 4 items : 6, 3000, 10000, -304 but the display is 6-->3000-->10000-->-304-->0-->0 . Where does the two "0" come from? And when I tried to Peek 2 times I expected the output to be 10000 but again two "0" are printed.

Here is what I have done:

```
public class Queue<T>
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The capacity of the Elements Collection
    /// </summary>
    private int _capacity;
    public int Capacity
    {
        get { return _capacity; }
        set { _capacity = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of elements currently in the queue.
    /// </summary>
    private int _length;
    public int Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
        set { _length = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The actual data elements stored in the queue.
    /// </summary>
    private T[] _elements;
    protected T[] Elements
    {
        get { return _elements; }
        set { _elements = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the index where we will dequeue.
    /// </summary>
    private int _frontIndex;
    public int FrontIndex
    {
        get { return _frontIndex; }
        set { _frontIndex = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the index where we will next enqueue a value. 
    /// It is calculated based on the Front Index, Length, and Capacity
    /// </summary>
    public int BackIndex
    {
        get { return (FrontIndex + Length) % Capacity; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public Queue()
    {
        Elements = new T[Capacity];
    }

    public Queue(int capacity)
    {
        Capacity = capacity;
        Elements = new T[Capacity];
    }

    #endregion

    #region public methods

    public void Enqueue(T element)
    {
        if (this.Length == Capacity)
        {
            IncreaseCapacity();
        }
        Elements[BackIndex] = element;
        Length++;
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (this.Length < 1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error: Queue is empty");
        }
        T element = Elements[FrontIndex];
        Elements[FrontIndex] = default(T);
        Length--;
        FrontIndex = (FrontIndex + 1) % Capacity;
        return element;
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (this.Length < 1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error: Queue is empty");
        }
        return Elements.First();
    }

    public T Min()
    {
        bool notSupport = false;
        try
        {
            T minItem = Elements.First();
            foreach (T temp in Elements)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Convert.ToDouble(minItem) > Convert.ToDouble(temp))
                        minItem = temp;
                }
                catch
                {
                    notSupport = true;

                }
            }
            return minItem;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (notSupport)
                throw (new InvalidOperationException("Error: Method not support this type."));
            else
                throw (new InvalidOperationException("Error: Queue is empty"));
        }
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        foreach (T item in Elements)
        {
            Console.Write(item);
            Console.Write("-->");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    #endregion

    #region protected methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Private function for increasing the size of the queue 
    /// if we run out of space and need to add another element
    /// </summary>
    protected void IncreaseCapacity()
    {
        this.Capacity++;
        this.Capacity *= 2;
        Queue<T> tempQueue = new Queue<T>(this.Capacity);
        while (this.Length > 0)
        {
            tempQueue.Enqueue(this.Dequeue());
        }
        this.Elements = tempQueue.Elements;
        this.Length = tempQueue.Length;
        this.FrontIndex = tempQueue.FrontIndex;
    }

    #endregion
}

//test client
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** Create queue type interger and enqueue some item: 6, 3000, 10000, -304 *** ");
        Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();
        queue.Enqueue(6);
        queue.Enqueue(3000);
        queue.Enqueue(10000);
        queue.Enqueue(-304);
        queue.Display();

        Console.WriteLine("*** Dequeue two item ***");
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue());
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue());

        Console.WriteLine("*** Peek two times ***");
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Peek());
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Peek());

        Console.WriteLine("*** Min value ***");
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Min());

        Console.WriteLine("*** Dequeue 2 item, queue is empty, and Dequeue mor item ***");
        try
        {
            queue.Dequeue();
            queue.Dequeue();
            queue.Dequeue();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("*** Peek empty queue ***");
        try
        {
            queue.Peek();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("*** Find min item in empty queue ***");
        try
        {
            queue.Min();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("*** Insert 5 item: 10, -3, 39, 2, 40000 ***");
        queue.Enqueue(10);
        queue.Enqueue(-3);
        queue.Enqueue(39);
        queue.Enqueue(2);
        queue.Enqueue(40000);
        queue.Display();

        Console.WriteLine("*** Peek two times ***");
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Peek());
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Peek());

        Console.WriteLine("*** Min value ***");
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Min());

        Console.WriteLine("*** Dequeue two item ***");
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue());
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue());


        Console.WriteLine("*** Create queue type double and enqueue some item: 6.4, 3000.322, 10000.333, -304.221 *** ");
        Queue<double> doubleQueue = new Queue<double>();
        doubleQueue.Enqueue(6.4);
        doubleQueue.Enqueue(3000.322);
        doubleQueue.Enqueue(10000.333);
        doubleQueue.Enqueue(-304.221);
        doubleQueue.Display();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel why not just make a class derived from `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` that adds the `Min()` and `Display()` methods.

Comment: Can you please show me the full implementation? i dont understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your IncreaseCapacity() method. Whenever the queue capacity is recalculated it's adding unnecessary entries which are showing up as those spurious zeros.

Answer (score 0):

> Where does the two "0" come from?

This is because in your constructor you initialize the `Elements`

```
Elements = new T[Capacity];
```

And the default value of an `int` is 0

> And when I tried to Peek 2 times I expected the output to be 10000 but
>   again two "0" are printed.

This is because in your implementation of the `Queue`, the elements don't move and stay on their position.

I suggest you to implement your functionality in an implementation where you use a `Queue` to store the elements. Something like this:

```
public class CustomQueue<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> queue;

    private int _capacity;
    public int Capacity
    {
        get { return _capacity; }
        set { _capacity = value; }
    }


    public CustomQueue()
    {
        this.queue = new Queue<T>();
    }

    public CustomQueue(int capacity)
    {
        this.Capacity = capacity;
        this.queue = new Queue<T>(capacity);
    }

    public void Enqueue(T element)
    {
        if (this.queue.Count == this.Capacity)
        {
            IncreaseCapacity();
        }

        this.queue.Enqueue(element);
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (this.queue.Count < 1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error: Queue is empty");
        }

        return this.queue.Dequeue();
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (this.queue.Count < 1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error: Queue is empty");
        }

        return this.queue.Peek();
    }

    public T Min()
    {
        bool notSupport = false;
        try
        {
            T minItem = this.queue.Peek();

            foreach (T temp in this.queue)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Convert.ToDouble(minItem) > Convert.ToDouble(temp))
                        minItem = temp;
                }
                catch
                {
                    notSupport = true;

                }
            }
            return minItem;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (notSupport)
                throw (new InvalidOperationException("Error: Method not support this type."));
            else
                throw (new InvalidOperationException("Error: Queue is empty"));
        }
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        foreach (T item in this.queue)
        {
            Console.Write(item);
            Console.Write("-->");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }


    protected void IncreaseCapacity()
    {
        this.Capacity++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @HarperSue Unfortunatly it's not easy to fix your code. I implemented a custom Queue which uses the original Queue to store the data. Hope this helps. It's always better to use the functionality of the framework and not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I tried to run again but now the test client method has error "System.Collections.Generic.Queue<int>" does not contain a definition for 'Display'

Comment: @HarperSue You have to create an instance of the `CustomQueue` and not the `Queue`. And you have to watch out, that the `Queue` in my class is the `Queue`from the .NET Framework and not your Queue implemenentation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to make a new class that does everything the built in [`Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does you can just make two extension methods that add on the two functions you want on to the existing `Queue<T>`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myQueue = new Queue<int>();
            myQueue.Enqueue(6);
            myQueue.Enqueue(3000);
            myQueue.Enqueue(1000);
            myQueue.Enqueue(-304);

            Console.WriteLine("Min: {0}", myQueue.MyMin());
            myQueue.Display();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static class QueueExtensionMethods
    {
        //Renamed to MyMin because Min already exists from System.Linq
        public static T MyMin<T>(this Queue<T> queue)
        {
            bool notSupport = false;
            try
            {
                T minItem = queue.First();
                foreach (T temp in queue)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToDouble(minItem) > Convert.ToDouble(temp))
                            minItem = temp;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        notSupport = true;

                    }
                }
                return minItem;
            }
            catch
            {
                if (notSupport)
                    throw (new InvalidOperationException("Error: Method not support this type."));
                else
                    throw (new InvalidOperationException("Error: Queue is empty"));
            }
        }

        public static void Display<T>(this Queue<T> queue)
        {
            foreach (T item in queue)
            {
                Console.Write(item);
                Console.Write("-->");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note I renamed `Min()` to `MyMin()` because thanks to `using System.Linq;` doing `myQueue.Min()` works out of the box without writing any code at all (but it does not throw a exception like your code does if the type does not support converting to a double).

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be multiple different problems with your `Queue` implementation. Most of them relate to the fact that you are using a circular array to hold your elements, which is a perfectly fine way to implement a queue, but in several spots in your code, the way you index this array is not correct.

I also noted a few other issues that may relate to an unfamiliarity with how certain things are generally handled in the c# language, such as

- Trying to convert the items of type `T` to `double` to compare them, instead of using an `IComparer<T>`.
- Using a backing field for each property, where you could just use auto properties.
- Exposing the setters of these properties as public, allowing problems such as a client of the class changing the number of elements (`Length = 10;`) without enqueueing or dequeueing any elements and invalidating your invariants.

As others have already mentioned, there is a standard .NET [`Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation available, that you could simply wrap or extend with the extra functionality you need.

Still I believe it might be useful to explicitly highlight some of these issues currently present in your code and how you could solve them. So I created a version that I believe addresses these, with the main changes highlighted with a `// ***` style comment.

```
public class Queue<T> 
{
    // *** You need to be able to compare elements in 'Min()' ***
    private readonly IComparer<T> _comparer;
    // *** Allocate a small initial size if no capacity given ***
    private const int DefaultCapacity = 4;

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The capacity of the Elements Collection
    /// </summary>
    public int Capacity
    {
        // *** The number of allocated elements == capacity ***
        get { return Elements.Length; } 
    }

    // *** For each of these properties:
    // (1) you don't need a backing field, you can use an "auto property".
    // (2) don't make the "set" operation available to clients of the class: 
    //     make it "private".

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of elements currently in the queue.
    /// </summary>
    public int Length { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The actual data elements stored in the queue.
    /// </summary>
    protected T[] Elements { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the index where we will dequeue.
    /// </summary>
    public int FrontIndex { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the index where we will next enqueue a value. 
    /// It is calculated based on the Front Index, Length, and Capacity
    /// </summary>
    public int BackIndex
    {
        get { return (FrontIndex + Length) % Capacity; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /*** Allows supplying a comparer to find the minimum */
    public Queue(IComparer<T> comparer = null) : this(DefaultCapacity, comparer)
    {
    }

    public Queue(int capacity, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        // *** Ensure capacity > 0 ***
        Elements = new T[capacity > 0 ? capacity : DefaultCapacity];
        _comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default; // *** We need a comparer ****
    }

    #endregion

    #region public methods

    public void Enqueue(T element)
    {
        if (this.Length == Capacity)
        {
            IncreaseCapacity();
        }
        Elements[BackIndex] = element;
        Length++;
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (this.Length < 1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error: Queue is empty");
        }
        T element = Elements[FrontIndex];
        Elements[FrontIndex] = default(T);
        Length--;
        FrontIndex = (FrontIndex + 1) % Capacity;
        return element;
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (this.Length < 1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error: Queue is empty");
        }
        return Elements[FrontIndex]; // *** You need to index by FrontIndex ***
    }

    // *** Added to allow easy enumeration. ***
    public IEnumerable<T> Items
    {
        get
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++)
                yield return Elements[(FrontIndex + i) % Capacity];
        }
    }

    public T Min() 
    {
        // *** Cannot get min if there are no items.
        if (Length < 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error: Queue is empty");

        // *** Need to start searching from FrontIndex
        var min = Elements[FrontIndex];
        for (var i = 1; i < Length; i++)
        {
            var item = Elements[(FrontIndex + i) % Capacity];
            // *** Need  the comparer for comparison of 'T'
            if (_comparer.Compare(min, item) > 0) // 'min' > 'item'
                min = item;
        }
        return min;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        foreach (T item in Items) // *** We can use the "Items" enumerable here.
        {
            Console.Write(item);
            Console.Write("-->");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    #endregion

    #region private methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Private function for increasing the size of the queue 
    /// if we run out of space and need to add another element
    /// </summary>
    private void IncreaseCapacity()
    {
        // *** Need to allocate a new larger array for the items
        var newElementsArray = new T[this.Capacity * 2];
        // *** And fill it with our current elements sequentially
        var ndx = 0;
        foreach (var item in Items)
            newElementsArray[ndx++] = item;

        // *** Now we can assign it and reset the front index.
        this.Elements = newElementsArray;
        this.FrontIndex = 0;
    }

    #endregion
}
```